# how to get command executed appended as output filename in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have batch script which read and executes command defined in command.txt on all the servers which ever mentioned in server.txt file using for loop.

problem is,am trying to get output/result file as "server_command.log" for each command executed.

I can easily get the server details but for commands, I need to get the last word from the command.txt file since each command has special character ie, /

command.txt content :

```
show /system1/firmware1
show /system1/fan1
```

server.txt will have ip address of target server :

```
10.1.1.101
10.1.1.103
10.1.1.105
```

output file am trying to get should be :

```
101.1.1.101_firmware1.log (file will contain fireware1 command output)
101.1.1.101_fan1.log (file will contain fan1 command output)
101.1.1.103_firmware1.log (file will contain fireware1 command output)
101.1.1.103_fan1.log (file will contain fan1 command output)
101.1.1.105_firmware1.log (file will contain fireware1 command output)
101.1.1.105_fan1.log (file will contain fan1 command output)
```

my batch file:

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in (.\config\serverlist.txt) do (
  echo _
  echo -----  Opening connection to: %%a at %TIME% -----  >> %LOGFILE%
  for /f "tokens=*" %%c in (.\config\commands.txt) do (
    set MyCmd=%%c
    set Server=%%a
    echo --------- %%c and %%a ------------------
    set MyLog=.\Logs\!Server!_%MyDate%.!MyCmd!.log
       .\plink -ssh %username%@!Server! -pw %password% "!MyCmd!" >> !MyLog!
  )
  echo. >> %LOGFILE%
  echo -----  Closing connection to: %%a at !TIME! -----  >> %LOGFILE%
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

replace your special symbol (`/`) with a space and use a simple `for` to get the last element:

```
...
set MyCmd=%%c
for %%X in (!MyCmd:/^= !) do set MyCmd=%%X
echo !MyCmd!
...
```